# Cannot resolve symbol for column name for SQL datasource

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, .net-4.5

I'm trying to select some data from a database table, but I can't seem to get the column name to resolve....

```
            var context = new NorthwindDataContext();

            return (
                from c in (context.Customers)
                select c.Country
                ).Distinct().ToList();
```

The column name Country exists and there is data in the database table but hovering over c.Country, I get

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'Country'
```

As an aside, for some reason, I needed to have context.Customers in brackets, or visual studio doesn't seem to resolve 'select', not sure if that has any impact...

Comment: You really *really* shouldn't need to put `context.Customers` in brackets. What happens if you remove them and try to compile?

Comment: Does Country truly exist on Customer? What does the Customers class look like?

Comment: @brumScouse: According to [this](http://merc.tv/img/fig/Northwind_mdb_physical.gif) is does.

Comment: Ok thats an ER diagram.  But what is the actual code telling you?

Comment: @JonSkeet I've I remove the brackets, the 'select' is also highlighted as not resolvable, the build succeeds.

Comment: @brumScouse I've viewed the database using Server explorer, can can see the table with the data and the columns I was expecting to see.

Comment: If the build succeeds, then it sounds like it's possibly some other plugin (ReSharper) or something like that. Try disabling plugins one at a time until you find out what's actually failing.

Comment: @Nav - Ok so you are still looking at the table in the database. Can you look at the template/generic type of the Customers property. I'm hazarding a guess its List<Customer> or some such, so actually eyeball the Customer class itself.

Comment: ok, I feel like a complete idiot... it was resharper causing the issue!!!

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question completely.